# Finding the roots of an equation and plotting them

Tags: plotting

```
ψn[n_, x_] := x SphericalBesselJ[n, x]
dψn[n_, x_] := ψn[n - 1, x] - n ψn[n, x]/x
Nn[n_, x_] := x SphericalBesselY[n, x]
dNn[n_, x_] := Nn[n - 1, x] - n Nn[n, x]/x
f[m_, n_, x_] := m ψn[n, m x] dNn[n, x] - Nn[n, x] dψn[n, m x]
```

[image]

There is a root of `f[Sqrt[9.8], 24, x]` between `9.61677463456185765` and `9.61677463456185768`.
The `Plot` function can't give the right picture with a correct `x` region. What's the problem?
How can I find it and how to `Plot` `f` in this interval?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I think the tag 'findroot' should be removed since the question is solely about plotting.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to ask Mathematica to treat your numbers as arbitrary-precision numbers by tagging the number of digits you'd like Mathematica to keep track of at the end of your numbers like this:

```
9.61677463456185765`20
```

This produces a plot:

```
Plot[
  f[Sqrt[9.8], 24, x] 10^8,
  {x, 9.61677463456185765`20, 9.61677463456185768`20}
]
```

In drawing the figure, the two endpoints of the $x$-axis will be treated as the same number if your `$MachinePrecision` is not enough. (This is probably because Mathematica uses machine-precision numbers for the plot range.)

You may want to try `ListPlot` instead:

```
ListPlot[
  Table[
    f[Sqrt[9.8], 24, x] 10^8,
    {x, 9.61677463456185765`20, 9.61677463456185768`20, 0.000000000000000001`20}
  ],
  Joined -> True,
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

and modify the tick numbers with the option `Ticks` as appropriate (if `DataRange` doesn't work).

Note that `9.8` is a machine-precision number. You may want to think about whether that's what you want. Your `f` gives a different result when the number is inputted as `98/10`—an exact number (i.e. `Precision[98/10]` is `Infinity`).